# InnoSetup: How to start the silent installation after showing my own form from the dll?

Tags: forms, dll, inno-setup, silent-installer

I need to start the silent installation after showing my own form on the screen.

How to do that?

Heres is my ISS code, an `OpenWizardForm` procedure is imported from my own DLL. It will open the modal form, accept the user's data, close the modal form and then continue execution.

```
[Setup]
DisableWelcomePage=yes
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  WizardForm.Width := 0;
  WizardForm.Height := 0;
  OpenWizardForm(WizardForm.Handle); // here is my own modal form will appear
  // and now the silent installation must be started
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a hack for this:

```
[Setup]
DisableWelcomePage=yes
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes


[Code]   

const
  WM_CLOSE = $0010;
  WM_KEYDOWN = $0100;
  WM_KEYUP = $0101;
  VK_RETURN = 13;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  WizardForm.Width := 0;
  WizardForm.Height := 0;
  OpenWizardForm(WizardForm.Handle);

  // Pressing the default "Install" button to continue the silent install
  PostMessage(WizardForm.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
  PostMessage(WizardForm.Handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);

  // Or can exit the wizard if the user has cancelled installation
  // PostMessage(WizardForm.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I couldn't find a means of having my setup auto execute after running for doing stuff like driver installs or updates...but now I do...dunno why I didn't think of this.

Comment: what is `WizardForm` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make the setup silent once it's started.
The only way is to pass the `/silent` or `/verysilent` parameter on the command line.